# Ms-access Combo Populate

Tags: ms-access, combobox, populate

For some reason my Combo box will not populate a text box field, i have done this on previous forms and even have working in different fields on this very form, but i cannot seem to get it to populate one text box. here is a picture to show what is happening, as well as the code. in theory it should work and all the properties are set correct. This combo box is from another table though.

```
Private Sub ProjectID_Change() 
Me.Client_Name.Value = Me.ProjectID.Column(2) 
End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combobox columns are numbered from (0) so you need to reference column 1 ;

```
Private Sub ProjectID_Change() 
    Me.Client_Name.Value = Me.ProjectID.Column(1) 
End Sub
```

And as suggested move it to the `AfterUpdate` event.

Comment: Hi sorry, that was an edit to check if the columns where wrong, the proper column should be (1) yes but still wont work.

Comment: If the combo is bound put the code in the After_Update event